# pysimplegui problem with running multiple scripts with different strings in Python

Tags: python, loops, pysimplegui

I'm having trouble trying to make pysimplegui work as I want.
I would like to open the program, enter my information, run "Extract",
let the script finish (it shows details in the output). Then on the same window, I would like to run another one using the same button "Extract" once the first script has finished running.

The best I can do is loop it and it opens a new window and closes the first.
How do I get it to just stay open and allow me to do another search without closing when the script is finished?

In other words, I want to open 1 GUI window and run multiple scripts using different parameters "keywords" or start/end dates. One after the other.

```
guivalues = ['', '', '', "localhost", "root", 'PASSWORD', '', ''];
while True:
    sg.theme('Dark2')
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Enter multiple Keywords, comma to separate')],
        [sg.Text('Keywords', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText()],
        [sg.Text('Start Date YYYY-MM-DD: ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[1])],
        [sg.Text('End Date YYYY-MM-DD: ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[2])],
        [sg.Text('Host (usually localhost): ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[3])],
        [sg.Text('User (usually root): ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[4])],
        [sg.Text('mySQL password: ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[5])],
        [sg.Text('Database: ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[6])],
        [sg.Text('Table: ', size=(20, 1)), sg.InputText(guivalues[7])],
        [sg.Output(size=(70, 15))],
        [sg.Button('Extract'), sg.Button('Close')]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Python to SQL', layout)
    event, guivalues = window.read()
    if event == 'Close':
        break
        window.Close()
    if event == 'Extract':
         XXX EXTRACTION CODE XXXXX
    window.read()  
    window.Close()
```

ISSUE RESOLVED

```
sg.theme('Dark2')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Enter multiple Keywords, comma to separate')],
    [sg.Button('Extract', bind_return_key=True ), sg.Button('Close')]
]
window = sg.Window('Python to SQL', layout)
while True:
    event, guivalues = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Quit'):
        break
    if event == 'Close':
        break
    if event == 'Extract':
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
```

The key is not looping the GUI window. Use the "While True" loop for the script doing the backend work. And within the while loop, you "read" the window for conditional "event" statements. THEN you put the conditionals within the loop. In other words

#GUI Stuff#
**then**

While True:
event, guivalues = window.read()
**then**
Conditionals

Comment: If I understand well, you want both windows to stay open simultaneously?

Comment: You can find the event loop `while` is for event read and event handler, not including the creation of a window, if you check any demo program in https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms

Comment: Thanks Everyone, its resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)